# JSF/primefaces - passing property to dialog

Tags: java, dialog, primefaces

I currently trying to pass some data from datatable to dialog and then confirm some action. My problem is that passing the bean to dialog works fine but when I try to save it by clicking the save button it appears to be null.

code:

```
<p:column>
 <p:commandButton value="Mark" update="showPlayers:display" oncomplete="userDialog.show()" >
  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{user}" target="#{manageUser.selectedUser}" />
 </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
...
<p:dialog header="Mark" widgetVar="userDialog" resizable="true" id="userDlg"
                       width="400" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">
    <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2"
           <!-- this below works fine -->
      <h:outputText value="#{manageUser.userSelected.email}"/>                      

      <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Save" actionListener="#{manageUser.addNewFeature}" oncomplete="userDialog.hide()" />

    </h:panelGrid>
 </p:dialog>
```

When I try in method `addNewFeature` work with bean userSelected it resolved to null and throw NullPointerException. I don't actually know where I lost reference to this instance. This bean is request scoped.

Thanks for any comments or answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. A @ViewScoped bean will live as long as you return null or void from
   the action methods (and thus navigate back to the same view).
2. A @RequestScoped bean will be garbaged by end of every request and
   recreated on every new requestm hereby losing all original
   properties.

Try change scope to view.

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html

Comment: I tried session scope hoping it will solved my troubles. So then I change the structure but thank you for your answer.